# Powershell, standalone OK, but scripted output is just newlines

Tags: .net-core, powershell-7.0

**Summary**

I am baffled that typing in my code in PS7 works like a charm, but when I put it in a script I seem to NOT get any output.

**Info**

Take a look at the following script, which runs without generating any errors:

```
"Iapetus elementary test script"
#Before doing anything ensure we are at least at powershell v6
#Official Powershell updates can be found here: https://aka.ms/powershell-release?tag=stable
if ($host.Version.Major -lt 6)
{
  throw "Minimum powershell version for this script is v6. Detected: "+$host.Version
}

#ensure colors are default to avoid printing black on black
#[Console]::ResetColor()

#clear the output screen
clear

# Locate the Iapetus core DLL
$IapetusBinFolder=$PSScriptRoot+"\..\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\net5.0"
$CoreDLL="SNG.Iapetus.Core.dll"
$IapetusCoreDLLPath=$IapetusBinFolder+"\"+$CoreDLL

#Add the Iapetus library to the powershell environment
"Loading "+$IapetusCoreDLLPath
Add-Type -Path $IapetusCoreDLLPath

#Open/Connect to the Iapetus instance
$instance=[SNG.Iapetus.Core.Iapetus]::Instance
"Iapetus instance loaded:"
$instance

# check out some of the static definitions
$staticdefs=$instance.StaticDefinitions;
"Iapetus.StaticDefinitions:"
$instance.StaticDefinitions | Get-Member
```

The output that it generates looks like this:
[image: Scripted:output are just newlines]

But here's the thing when I type the same statements in powershell:

[image: Manual: this is what I need]

So obviously I am missing something here... Using powershell 7 and my app which is written using C#/.NET core 5

**Question**

How do I get to fix this, and what is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: btw using the $staticdefs intermediate varbable or direct member access (as in the script) makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally Found a fix, though I am unsure *why* this fixes the error.

when I change the lines

```
#Open/Connect to the Iapetus instance
$instance=[SNG.Iapetus.Core.Iapetus]::Instance
"Iapetus instance loaded:"
$instance
```

into

```
#Open/Connect to the Iapetus instance
$instance=[SNG.Iapetus.Core.Iapetus]::Instance
"Iapetus instance loaded:"
$instance | Get-Member
```

then the staticdefs suddenly also generates output

```
$staticdefs=$instance.StaticDefinitions;
"Iapetus.StaticDefinitions:"
$staticdefs | Get-Member
```

So this a *partial* answer, it tells how to fix/work around the problem, but it doesn not answer *why* it's behavior is diffrently from the command line and script.

Resulting in the following screenshot that shows the output that I actually expected:

[image: Fixed output]